# How can I stub rand in minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, minitest, stub

I've tried `Random.stub :rand, 1 do ... end` and `Kernel.stub :rand, 1 do ... end` and `Class.stub :rand, 1 do ... end` (because when I run `self.class` where I run `rand(2)` I get `Class`). I've also tried replacing `rand(2)` with `Random.rand(2)` but it doesn't help.

So how do I stub out rand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rand` is part of the `Kernel` module that is mixed into every class. To stub it, you need to call `stub` on the object where `rand` is being called.

It's probably easiest to see in an example. In the following code, `rand` is a private instance method of the `Coin`, because `Coin` implicitly inherits from `Object` and `Kernel`. Therefore I need to stub on the *instance* of `Coin`.

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/mock"

class Coin
  def flip
    rand(0..1) == 1 ? "heads" : "tails"
  end
end

class CoinTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_flip
    coin = Coin.new
    coin.stub(:rand, 0) do
      assert_equal("tails", coin.flip)
    end
  end
end
```